# Can a User Group Create Drafts of New Entries Only?

Tags: workflow, entry, draft, user-groups

I'm trying to set up a workflow where I have a group of "Drafters" who can create new entries but the new entry is not published by default. I've made the following setting for this group.

[image: screenshot of group settings]

However, when I log in as a user within this group, the user is not allowed to create a new entry, even though their permission explicitly says they can create new entries. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something here?

Yes, you’re missing a bugfix that should be going out today ;)